# Match against variables (or otherwise introduce abstraction for match logic)

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, ml

It's possible to match against literals (obviously):

```
let res = match x with 
  | "abc" -> 1
  | "def" as x -> something_else x
```

**Q**: However, is it possible to match against the values of variables, so literals aren't repeated throughout the code?

```
let abc = "abc"
let def = "def"
let res = match x with
  | (abc) -> 1
  ...
```

(The above will of course not match against `abc`, but will match in every case)

In **F#**, an *active pattern* can be used:

```
let (|IsAbc|IsDef|) str = if str = abc then IsAbc(str)
                     else if str = def then IsDef(str)
                     ...
let res = match x with 
          | IsAbc x -> 1
          | IsDef x -> somethingElse x
```

This allows abstraction of match logic and defining literals only once. How could I achieve this in **OCaml**?

The closest I got is this: *but* it feels somewhat clumsy?

```
let is_abc str = str = abc 
let is_def str = str = def
...
let res = match x with
  | x when is_abc x -> 1
  | x when is_def x -> something_else x
```

Or using `if`: *but* it looks less elegant than `match` (also, to match on `y`, *n* edits have to be made, compared with 1 when using `match`)

```
let res = if x = abc then 1
     else if x = def then something_else x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [C-style preprocessor](https://github.com/mjambon/cppo).

```
#define ABC "abc"
#define DEF "def"

let res = match x with 
  | ABC -> 1
  | DEF as x -> something_else x
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `when` is essentially the best you can do in OCaml. I don't think it looks any clumsier than the F# equivalent that you give. But it's a question of taste perhaps.

You can also just break down and use an `if` expression. That's what I would do personally. I don't see any advantage in pretending that OCaml `match` is more general than it really is.

You might think of it as a similar tradeoff to `if` and `switch` in C-like languages. If you want to compare against a set of values known at compile time, `switch` is far more efficient. But it doesn't try to be a generalized `if`.

Comment: I see.. The **F#** partial pattern definition looks clumsier, but it's defined once and it looks a bit nicer at the use site (which matters more in real usecases) than the **OCaml** version. And, while might be considered questionable, `switch` in C-like languages lends itself to use like this: `switch (true) { case x == abc: ...; break; case x == def: ...; }`

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching bring exhaustivity, if you use variables you are more in a simple if expression situation.
You can be tempted to use match for his elegant syntax and test against a great number of possible values like :

```
match x with 
| value A -> function A
| value B -> function B
| ...
| value N -> function N
```

If you face this situation, you could use a structure to map the values to the corresponding function.

Match syntax is so elegant that it is easy to try to use it for every situation, but the purpose is important to preserve simplicity of the language.